# Key bindings for a repetitive action in VIM editor

Tags: vim, key-bindings, cscope

I use Vim + Cscope for coding in a large repository.

With the integration of cscope in Vim, say to find the definition of variable,
i have to type ":cs f g " on vi's command line.

Is there a easy way to map these actions? Like say if i type (Ctrl + g) on a particular variable, it automatically goes to the variable's definitions ? (Ctrl + s) shows the list of occurrences of the symbol under the cursor ?

Comment: *emacs* :P. Just kidding, I'm a vim user, although I've never tried to do this before, it would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

`nnoremap <C-g> :cs f g<enter>`

For more information, see `:help map-commands`.

Comment: nnoremap <C-g> :cs f g <cword> <enter>, worked like a charm .. sorry for the late ack.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
nnoremap <C-g> :execute "normal! cs\ f\ g"<cr>
```